# Quick way of combining/mergining objects in powershell

Tags: powershell, object, merge

I have two objects containing over 20 properties each.

The first is from Get-ADUser, the second is built using an SQL Query from an Access Database.

So right now I have for example $object1 , $object2.

I am in the process of combining these objects by doing a custom object, like this for example:

```
    $properties = [ordered]@{
    'a'=$object1.propertyX;
    'b'=$object1.propertyY;
    'c'=$object2.propertyX;
    ...
    }

$CombinedObject = New-Object –TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
```

That will work, however it will take a LOT of time to type out the ~40 properties of each object in total.

Is there a quicker way to combine two objects with all their properties in one custom object which would save me all that typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a hashtable for the properties of each object, and make an object from that. I would suggest prefixing AD and SQL on each property to know what object it came from and to avoid conflicts.

```
$PropertyHT = @{}
$object1.psobject.properties.name | ForEach-Object{ $PropertyHT.Add("AD$_",$Object1.$_) }
$object2.psobject.properties.name | ForEach-Object{ $PropertyHT.Add("SQL$_",$Object2.$_) }
$CombinedObject = New-Object –TypeName PSObject -Property $PropertyHT
```

Comment: Oh this is great, quite logicial when you you how. I will keep that in my toolkit for a while. Thanks for teaching me this today!

Comment: @Rakha [Here's a potentially useful article](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/)

Comment: `New-Object PSObject` *booo*.  In seriousness, though, you can just `[pscustomobject]$PropertyHT`

Comment: True, we can just cast it!